# Play framework compilation errors not showing in production server

Tags: java, linux, playframework-2.0, debian

I'm trying to deploy my play application in production server. I have checked out the code in the server and trying play compile. But i'm getting the below error but it doesn't show any error to look into. How can i see the errors which causes compilation failure?

```
root@test-1:/var/www/myapp# play clean compile
[info] Loading project definition from /var/www/myapp/project
[info] Set current project to vizual (in build file:/var/www/myapp/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2013 7:16:16 PM
[info] Updating {file:/var/www/myapp/}vizual...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 18 Java sources to  
/var/www/myapp/target/scala-2.10/classes...
Killed

root@backend-1:/var/www/myapp# play compile
[info] Loading project definition from /var/www/myapp/project
[info] Set current project to vizual (in build file:/var/www/myapp/)
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 18 Java sources to   
/var/www/myapp/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 22 s, completed Aug 4, 2013 7:23:49 PM
```

Please note that the same code compiles and works fine locally.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI this isn't the best practice for deploying your application to a production server. You should run a `dist` command from a clean checkout (preferably from your build server), and then move the resultant packaged application onto your prod server, unpack it and start it up. This way you won't need need Play to be installed on your production server (although it would still need an installation of Java). Following the best practice also circumvents this current problem you're having because it doesn't involve compiling on your production server.

Comment: @Avik, but i saw this as the first option for production here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Production

Comment: Understood. But as the documentation states, this is only one of the ways to deploy your application in production mode. If you're having problems with this approach of pulling the code and running Play, you should probably try some of the other ways mentioned in the docs (in particular the instructions for creating a standalone version of your application).